# SQLIOSIM fails to start when using UNC path

Tags: sql-server, performance, ntfs, unc, nas

I'm trying to run SQLIOSIM on NAS cluster's NTFS shared folder. Here's the command line:

```
sqliosim.com -dir \\c16\vol1cifs -size 512 -d 600
```

But it repeatedly fails to create files during the setup due to following error:

Error:

> 0x80070057 Error Text: Description: Unable to get volume name for
>   mount point \c16\vol1cifs\

`vol1cifs` - NTFS shared folder, that can be opened and edited on the same client where SQLIOSIM is installed, without any problem. According to SQLIOSIM description it does supports UNC path.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help. Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some investigations, there maybe permission issue, related to file modify permissions.
Workaround:
Create file of a required size on NAS volume before running SQLIOSIM